# Python 2 on MAC OSX in Visual Studio Code

Tags: macos, visual-studio, python-2.7

I am a Python 2 developer and I have everything working fine in Windows 7 visual studio 2015. I was wondering if anyone got the IDE and Visual Studio Code working on a Mac in OS X. If so, maybe you could give a few hints on setting it up and downloading. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use **brew** to install all this on your mac. It is a package manager such as apt in Debian Linux or composer for php.

You can find all informations here: https://brew.sh

I know it is probably to late after 9 month and you already managed everything.